# Android: how to get the number of milliseconds since January 1st 1970 for a defined date?

Tags: android, date, milliseconds

I have seen this post which explains how to get the number of milliseconds since 1970 for the CURRENT DATE:

[how to get the number of seconds passed since 1970 for a date value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785965/how-to-get-the-number-of-seconds-passed-since-1970-for-a-date-value)

My question is: how to get this value in milliseconds for any date ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Since 1970 (I'm assuming you mean 1st January 1970) in which timezone? May sound daft, but the user's phone will give you a time in their timezone and do you want the milliseconds since midnight first January in that timezone or in GMT/UTC?

Comment: Hi ! I want the milliseconds in the same time zone as the date entered as input. Let's say that it is the time zone of the user. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Calendar c = new Calendar();</strike>

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
// year, month, day, hourOfDay, minute
c.set(1990, 7, 12, 9, 34);
long millis = c.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have got the rror "Cannot instantiate type Calendar". Do you know how to solve this error ? Thanks.

Comment: Ops sorry, that is a protected constructor. Wrote that from the top of my head. Fixed the example.

Comment: Thanks !! Nevertheless, I have got a kind of bug... When I write Date d = new Date(millis); after long millis = c.getTimeInMillis(); I have got a date which is offsetted of one month compared to what it should ! With the date in your example, it returns: 1990/8/12 and not 1990/7/12... How do you explain this ?? Thanks.

Comment: `Calendar.set()` month values range from 0 (january) to 11 (december). So this is the correct date, we set august here, not july.

Comment: If you don't want to get confused, you can replace the number (7 here) with a calendar month constant (`Calendar.AUGUST` here). This way it's clear and increases code readability.